# NSOperation cancelAllOperations takes too long to cancel operations

Tags: iphone

I have an NSOperationQueue to which i have added my custom class's objects(inherits from NSOperation) i have set the "setMaxConcurrentOperationCount" to be 1. But when i cancel all the operations like this:

[mOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];

it takes about 10 -15 seconds sometimes to cancel them all.

NSOperationQueue contains about 60-80 tasks(Operations).

Initially i was canceling the operations in main thread which obviously blocked the main thread but now i have done that in a different thread.But my main issue is that it takes too long.
Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation should check to see if it's been cancelled more often (e.g. in its implementation of `-main`).

Beyond that, run a sampler to see what is taking all that time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think "main" will only be called after "start" which in turn checks to see if the NSOperation is not cancelled so is there really a need for a check. ?

Comment: @Suny it depends on what is taking all that time. checking in `-main` matters when your operation takes a long time to complete and you can exit `-main` cleanly.